# Are the Knights of Ren Sith?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, sith, kylo-ren

In Star Wars: The Force Awakens we learn that Kylo Ren is >! a member of "Knight of Ren". We also learn that this is the team that

> slaughtered Luke's Jedi students.

So we have a group of fighters, and one of them(Kylo Ren) is a Dark Side of the force user.

They take orders from Snoke, who seems to be a Force user.

So this team are Sith? Or is a new order , calling themselves "Knight of Ren", who continue the "legacy" of Sith and what the difference between them? Are they something like Inquisitorius? And what Ren could possibly mean?

[image: Also in this image we see, Kylo with (?) Knights of Ren.! Are they part of the Force, or they just Fighters who take orders from Snoke?]

Comment: They appear wanna be sith and this was confirmed when kylo needed to compete his training

Comment: The other question goes over whether or not Ren is a Sith. If he is not a Sith, but *is* a Knight of Ren, then the Knights of Ren cannot mean that they are necessarily Sith.

Comment: They are the Knights who say Neeeee-Ren

Comment: It stands to reason that if the Master of the Knights of Ren (KR) isn't a Sith, as the lnked answer shows, they aren't either. And we know basically nothing about them at this point